# how to say "OR" in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

- I have one parent schema that will hold a child schema.
- The child schema that the parent will hold is going to be x **X** *OR* **Y**.
- How can I say that in mongoose?

```js
const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
// some properties
})

const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
// some properties
})

const parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  file: (imageSchema OR videoSchema) // how to make that happen?!
})
```

Comment: Is [mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) what are you looking for?

Comment: @J.F., no, because validations by the child schema is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [discriminator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)

```
const parentSchema = new Schema({ test: String },
  { discriminatorKey: 'file' });

const Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema );

const Image = Parent.discriminator('Image', new Schema({
// some properties
}));

const Video = Parent.discriminator('Video', new Schema({
 // some properties
}));
```